# Highchart axis max with multiple axes

Tags: highcharts, max, axes

I'm using multiple axes and I set one axis to use a max. If it is the only axis shown then the max works ok, just what I want. But if another axis is also shown the first axis max can change to be a bigger value. How can I get it to show its max, and not above it?

To see this go to http://jsfiddle.net/bx9sB/ . This has 3 axis, and the temperature axis has a max of 30.
Untick all the axes, and then click the Temperature. The max is 30, great. Next click to show the Pressure axis. Now the temperature axis has gone up to 35, instead of 30. How can I get it to stay on 30.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'°C';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            opposite: true,                
            max: 30

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall',
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mm';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#4572A7'
                }
            }

        }, { // Tertiary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +' mb';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#AA4643'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mm'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            type: 'spline',
            color: '#AA4643',
            yAxis: 2,
            data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' mb'
            }

        }, {
            name: 'Temperature',
            color: '#89A54E',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set alignTicks:false

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bx9sB/4/

```
alignTicks:false
```

Comment: Thanks this works for both the jsfiddle in the question, and also this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bx9sB/3/ with min, max on the 3rd axis.

Comment: If the grid lines look messy, it's a good idea to hide them for the secondary axis by setting gridLineWidth to 0. As used above in question.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `min` parameter as 0, then all should work properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/bx9sB/1/

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem to work for the 3rd axis. On http://jsfiddle.net/bx9sB/2/ I set a min: 1005, max:1025 for the Pressure axis, but it then has a max of 1030 when all the axes are shown.